# How to solve equation for many parameters?

Tags: matlab, plot, coordinates, linear-equation

I would like to solve an equation for modulus: `m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)` in MATLAB. I have the variables `x1,x2,y1,y2` and I can do it for a single case. However, I would like to calculate the m for different sets of `x1,x2,y1,y2`, i.e. to get modulus of each sample. Let's say I have three samples which variables are respectively:

```
x1 = 1, 2, 5
x2 = 0.5, 2, 3 
y1 = 3,2,5
y2 = 8,3,1
```

How do I get `m` for each sample?

I have one more question to this topic. I have to plot a line, which is a slope of the linear part of graph. The line start point has `x1(1)`, `y1(1)` coordinates, and end point `x2(1)`, `y2(1)` etc., like above in my first question. I have to do this for the respective 3 graphs which are on one plot.
I tried this but it gives me a random line on the graph:

```
x1 = [1, 2, 5]; 
x2 = [0.5, 2, 3]; 
y1 = [3,2,5]; 
y2 = [8,3,1]; 
hold on 
x = [x1, y1] 
y = [x2, y2] 
plot(x,y)
```

What would be another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a `.`:

```
x1 = [1, 2, 5];
x2 = [0.5, 2, 3];
y1 = [3,2,5];
y2 = [8,3,1];
m=(y2-y1)./(x2-x1) 

m =

   -10   Inf     2
```

The `.` operator makes all operations run *element wise*, thus `m(1)` will be `(y2(1)-y1(1))/(x2(1)-x1(1))`, `m(2)` will be based on the second entries and so forth.

Comment: @KasiaKępa if this answer worked for you, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the check mark below the vote arrows on the left of this post. This will signify you no longer need help.